JS to scribble (and self erase) a web page
I was wondering, how can I create something similar to the scribble (and self-erase) effect found on this website?
Example: https://www.bornfight.studio/
Thank you!
I found similar scripts but nothing that I don’t understand how to make the scribble self-disappear after few lines.
Similar example: https://jsfiddle.net/loktar/dQppK/23/


var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    painting = false,
    lastX = 0,
    lastY = 0,
    lineThickness = 1;

canvas.width = canvas.height = 600;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);

canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
    painting = true;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    lastX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    lastY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
};

canvas.onmouseup = function(e){
    painting = false;
}

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
    if (painting) {
        mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

        // find all points between        
        var x1 = mouseX,
            x2 = lastX,
            y1 = mouseY,
            y2 = lastY;


        var steep = (Math.abs(y2 - y1) > Math.abs(x2 - x1));
        if (steep){
            var x = x1;
            x1 = y1;
            y1 = x;

            var y = y2;
            y2 = x2;
            x2 = y;
        }
        if (x1 > x2) {
            var x = x1;
            x1 = x2;
            x2 = x;

            var y = y1;
            y1 = y2;
            y2 = y;
        }

        var dx = x2 - x1,
            dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1),
            error = 0,
            de = dy / dx,
            yStep = -1,
            y = y1;
        
        if (y1 < y2) {
            yStep = 1;
        }
       
        lineThickness = 5 - Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) *(x2-x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2-y1))/10;
        if(lineThickness < 1){
            lineThickness = 1;   
        }

        for (var x = x1; x < x2; x++) {
            if (steep) {
                ctx.fillRect(y, x, lineThickness , lineThickness );
            } else {
                ctx.fillRect(x, y, lineThickness , lineThickness );
            }
            
            error += de;
            if (error >= 0.5) {
                y += yStep;
                error -= 1.0;
            }
        }



        lastX = mouseX;
        lastY = mouseY;

    }
}
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>




Do you have looked at the console or F12 to read the Javascript? Interesting effect by the way.

I read the page source but I don’t even understand which script produces this effect.

Here I found something about SVG. https://www.bornfight.studio/_next/static/chunks/211-0c6254f8fd47bb5e.js

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As a side note: this sort of redrawing of a canvas very often can be very cpu and/or gpu intensive - a potential battery flattener for your users.

The trick to this is to maintain a list of points. The event handlers will update this list, and a render function will draw stuff on the screen.
Check out the following code.


class Point {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

const TOTAL_ALLOWED_POINTS = 10;
let CANVAS_WIDTH;
let CANVAS_HEIGHT;
let context;

const pointList = [];

function setupCanvas() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  CANVAS_WIDTH = canvas.width;
  CANVAS_HEIGHT = canvas.height;

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    const cursorPosition = new Point(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);

    // Add this point to the list so it can be rendered.
    pointList.push(cursorPosition);

    // Since the list of points is supposed to be finite,
    // remove the point that was added first (FIFO).
    if (pointList.length > TOTAL_ALLOWED_POINTS - 1) {
      pointList.shift();
    }
  });

  // Start drawing stuff.
  requestAnimationFrame(renderPoints);
}

function renderPoints() {
  if (!context) return;

  context.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);

  context.beginPath();
  pointList.forEach((point, index) => {
    if (index === 0) return;

    const previousPoint = pointList[index - 1];

    context.moveTo(previousPoint.x, previousPoint.y);
    context.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
  });
  context.closePath();
  context.stroke();

  requestAnimationFrame(renderPoints);
}

setupCanvas();
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 Canvas</title>
    <style>
      #canvas {
        border: 1px solid gray;
      }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>



The variable TOTAL_ALLOWED_POINTS defines how many points are to be rendered on the screen at a time.
And the variable pointList contains the list of actual points to be rendered.
Inside the mousemove event handler, we add the coordinates of the mouse event. Then, check if the pointList variable contains the allowed number of points. If this variable has overflowed, we pop out the very first point that had been inserted. This creates the trailing effect you see when you run the snippet.
Inside the render function renderPoints, we first clear the canvas, so that the points we had drawn in the last render are no longer displayed. Then draw a line segment between the points.
Please note that I am using requestAnimationFrame that continuously calls the renderPoints method, regardless of whether the point list had changed. But, you can also call the renderPoints method inside the event handler.
